# Random crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS on core data object entities comparison

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am facing this weird random crash where I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on an object that exists. I am totally stumped on why this is happening. The code in the image executes without any issues 99.99% of the time. I saw this crash second time and that when I thought I should figure out what might be going wrong. I am executing this code on the main thread and the crash line has two core data objects. This shouldn't be a concurrency issue because it's only used in this class. Scary part is that object is there, values are there, still, I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any ideas why this might be happening? [image]

Let me know if you guys need more info. And thanks in advance for your help. :)

**EDIT 1**
Definition of Employee and EmployeeForTask (the class declarations are empty and has no variable defined in it, it just inherits from NSManagedObject)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the definition for the `id` property in your `Employee` class? Is it an implicitly unwrapped optional?

Comment: Sorry, also the `EmployeeForTask` class.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen Thanks for your time, I have updated the question with for both Employee and EmployeeForTask definition. Both the ids are optional.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm rather stumped right now. Can you try a `po emp.id == empForTask.id` and see what that does in the debugger?

Comment: I can totally understand :(. I have spent over 8 hours going over the code and trying to figure out what might be going wrong and that's when I posted here. :(
I will try to do the po you suggested next time when I am able to reproduce the crash. So far, I have only been able to reproduce it twice. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: What does your core data stack look like? is it possible that the backing context has been released?

Comment: Do both arrays of Employees come from an NSManagedObjectContext associated with the main thread?

Comment: @JonRose Since I posted the question, I haven't been able to reproduce the crash. I will share the core data stack if I am able to reproduce it while debugging.

Comment: I don't mean the call stack.  What does your core-data setup look like? Are you using NSPersistentContainer? are you using child contexts?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable NSZombies. Zombies helps to detect these kind of crashes by logging problem in console. you can enable zombies by :Click on Product⇒Edit Scheme to open the sheet and set the Enable Zombie Objects check box

When building app on real device then disable Zombies. Otherwise app will not run on device.

Comment: Jagdeep, I have Zombies enabled already. Nothing there. Plus there is no real proof of how well Zombies work in Swift.